# Is it possible to save and read feather file in compressed zip format in R?

Tags: r, zip, feather

I need to save feather data in a more compact format. After making several tests I found that after using the "zip" function the size of the "feather" data file reduce up to 90%.

```
library(feather)
library(zip)

# Write data in feather format
write_feather(df, "data.feather)

# Write data in zip feather format
zip("data.feather.zip", "data.feather")

# How to have commands like these ones without using disk space for temp file?
write_feather(df, "data.feather.zip", format = "zip")
df <- read_feather("data.feather.zip", format = "zip")
```

So, there is a simple question - does anyway to save data as a "feather" file with let say argument "compressed = zip" to save disk space.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the library `arrow`. You can save as .parquet with compression. Similar performance as with feather, but with much smaller files.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be feather, you can use `fst` to read and write compressed data frames. e.g. write with 80% compression `fst::write_fst(df, 'mydat.fst', compress = 80)`

Comment: Also this might help, though did not directly answer your question, I know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes/

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks for this great advice. I checked "fst". Looks very cool. The only one question - Is it possible to read "fst" files in Python? as it's possible for feather format. Thanks!

Comment: No, not possible (at least with premade tools) at this time